# How the heck do you do superscript (and subscript)?

Tags: support, formatting

I have been trying to reformat a recent post which calls for superscript to a footnote, and I will be danged if I can see how to do it without getting into (sup) with the little wedgie thingies — which doesn't seem to work here: as soon as I put them in the text they disappear, like this: 11 (that was `1<sup>1`) — or rewriting the entire block of text in HTML.

Example..[see this answer and last para as well as the comments below it
.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505250/what-is-the-first-documented-usage-of-the-gay-culture-term-daddy/505257?noredirect=1#comment1221510_505257)

[An unanswered question on the topic.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/can-we-improve-our-sub-and-superscript-or-footnote-formatting)

How the heck do you do superscripts, at the beginning and also the end of text? And why don't we have a button to make it more convenient? Or am I missing something?

Comment: In order to see what I am talking about, you need to click on [edit] and check the text and code.

Comment: Just please, when you click on [EDIT] careful not to make smudges...

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with regular HTML notation in accordance with the following coding:

> <sup>1</sup>

When you use this code in your post, it produces a 1 that looks like this: <sup>1</sup>

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks! This thread also has some guidance on the subject. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155778/superscript-in-markdown-github-flavored

Comment: I'm sorry...{curly brackets} are supposed to  work like <angle brackets> (wedgie thingies)? Or I should _only_ use angle brackets?

Comment: Gotcha, @sumelic , and thanks. This has been confusing enough for an old guy like me who has to depend on his teen-age daughter for help in HTML. BTW, even she had to struggle with it, and finally gave up due to the peculiarities of the site.

Comment: What other HTML codes work here? Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: @JohnLawler: I wish I knew. I figured this one out a few years ago by trial and error—but there must be a usable HTML reference list for this site somewhere. Do you know, sumelic? tchrist? Andrew Leach? Laurel? I gather from Andrew Leach's answer that the particular HTML code set that EL&U uses is called Markdown, but I don't know what its powers and limitations are, except that it evidently doesn't support small caps by simple HTML tagging.

Comment: @JohnLawler https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox

Answer (score 4):

Markdown supports a limited subset of HTML. Superscript and subscript tags are included:

> `Text <sup>up</sup> Text <sub>down</sub>`
>
> Text <sup>up</sup> Text <sub>down</sub>

Some fonts come with a full or nearly-full set of superscript and subscript glyphs. Georgia Pro, the font used here, doesn't; but it does come with numbers which you can enter using Unicode references. Exactly how depends on your operating system; you may be reduced to using charmap or something similar.

> ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉

You can also use a utility such as https://yaytext.com/tiny-text/ which will create Unicode characters for you. It has to make some assumptions and not every character is available. It also ends up a bit small here.

> Text ˢᵘᵖᵉʳˢᶜʳᶦᵖᵗ

However another utility at the same site does a reasonable job of small capitals, which aren't easy otherwise and which are useful in dictionary references:

> Over, *see* ᴄʀɪᴄᴋᴇᴛ.

It's probably worth adding that if you *want* an angle-bracket to appear, you either need to enclose it in code-quotes (that's the backtick quote) or use the HTML entity `&lt;`

Comment: Being that this is a site that would greatly benefit from a font that uses "a full or nearly-full set of superscript and subscript glyphs" , why are we using Georgian Pro?

Comment: Well, generally only numbers are required. I find myself wanting small capitals more. And actually, the number of fonts available as web fonts with a complete character set is **very** small.

Comment: Well, what I am thinking is that sometimes footnotes come in different flavors i.e. (\*), (\*\*) and a variety of symbols which are not numbers.  Sorry, I am kinda ignorant on this stuff. and if my question seems asinine please let me know.

Comment: Does this not beg the question.."Which font works best for the purposes of EL&U?" Or maybe, "How is our present font impeding posts"?

Comment: You may need to mug up on HTML entities like `&dagger; &ddagger;` and things like `\*` to preserve an asterisk as an asterisk. (I edited your comment to put it right). Also, if you search Meta for ***font georgia*** you'll find a number of posts.

Comment: Thanks...I do admit that I was lost trying to do that correctly...your continuing help is an inspiration for me. I think maybe we could do with some "markup for dummies" here...in a FAQ or sumpin'

Comment: @Cascabel I recall seeing something of that sort in some meta, not on ELU perhaps.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage the use of unicode substitutions for regular alpha-numerical characters; you don't know what tools will or won't have trouble for them. Those unicode characters should only be used for their intended uses (often in maths/science.)

Comment: The Unicode characters for raised ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹  and lowered ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉  numerals are handy, and also letters for formal linguistics like ʷ ʸ ʰ ⁿ ᵗ ᵈ ˢ and ᵢ ⱼ ᵣ ᵤ ᵥ ᵦ ᵩ ᵪ.